# How to stop "Thread History" (in "Thread Views") after JVM exits?

Tags: jprofiler

The *Thread history* in *Thread Views* continues running, even if the JVM exits and is only kept alive by JProfiler (using *Keep VM alive*). With this behaviour I see a lot of useful data for the time when the JVM is running and a growing amount of useless data after that (all threads are waiting, in my case).

I tried using a trigger *JVM exit* with *Stop recording* action, but this does not stop the *Thread History*.

The trigger works, which I verified using a *Print message* action.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JProfiler always has to keep track of threads, so the thread history has no recording options.

If the growing time line in the keep-alive state is bothering you, I would recommend to save a snapshot. In the snapshot, everything is static.